# Android Byte Array not recognized

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and I'm trying to declare and use a small byte array but I am getting errors I don't understand.

The code in question is:

```
public class RedActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    byte[] myBuf = new byte[20]; // <-- Compiler likes this line
    myBuf[0] = 0x23; // <-- Compiler barfs on this line
```

the declaration line seems to be accepted by the compiler but the assignment line where I try to assign 0x23 to the first entry of the myBuf Array causes the following complaints to be displayed:

```
Error:(105, 11) error: ']' expected
Error:(105, 12) error: ';' expected
Error:(105, 14) error: illegal start of type
Error:(105, 15) error: <identifier> expected
```

Furthermore, when I hover over the offending line in the Android Studio editor I get things like "Unknown Class myBuf; Identifier Expected; and unexpected token

I'm pretty new to Android and really new to Android studio and I'm hoping someone can shove me in the right direction.  It seems like I don't have something set up quite right in Android studio because the Java syntax looks correct to me but maybe one of you guys see something that I've overlooked.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
myBuf[0] = 0x23; // <-- Compiler barfs on this line
```

That is because that line is not in a method. Move that to inside your `onCreate()` method, for example.

Comment: Good God... my own stupidity is so frequently the cause of my problems... thanks for that.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

try casting to a byte

myBuf[0] = (byte)0x23; // <-- Compiler barfs on this line

Comment: Not necessary unless the constant >= 0x80, and doesn't address the actual problem as evinced by the error message.